# C# Get type location within the project structure

Tags: c#

C# 7, .Net 4.7.2

In a simple but big .net project I have a quite normal structure.

- MyProject

  - Properties
  - References
  - SomeFolder
  - SomeOtherFolder

    - MyClass.cs

How can I get the structural path to MyClass.cs from code?

The result should be *MyProject/SomeOtherFolder/MyNamespace.MyClass*

(I'm just looking for the string, I don't need a reference or anything fancy)

**Clarification**
I'm working in a regular Console project, no AddIn. The project is quite big, so it would be really helpful to be able to do this by code and not manually. I want to do this at runtime.

**Additional information**
The typeof(MyClass).FullName does NOT fit the structural path. The namespaces differ from the project structure.

**Additional information II**
I'm searching for a method that takes the type or name or some other information of MyClass and returns *MyProject/SomeOtherFolder/MyNamespace.MyClass*.

Comment: What is the context ? When do you need this information ? at runtime ? in a Visual Studio plugin ?

Comment: You can use the full type name, if namespaces fit the project structure

Comment: Please have a look at the edits in the question post

Comment: The typeof(MyClass).FullName does NOT fit the structural path. The namespaces differ from the project structure.

Comment: Probably going to need the [Visual Studio object model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) for this.

Comment: I can easily get the namespace by reading typeof(MyClass).Namespace or simply by reading typeof(MyClass).Fullname. I don't know how the the folder structure.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the path of a source file, you can declare a utility function with a `string` parameter marked with the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath` attribute, and have that function return the value of that parameter. This will give you the full path to the source file of the caller.

So, that would be as follows:

```
public static class Utilities
{
    public static string GetSourceFilePath( [CallerFilePath] string sourceFileName = "" )
    {
        return sourceFileName;
    }
}
```

You call it simply like this:

```
string myPath = Utilities.GetSourceFilePath(); // no parameter!
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mike. How do I have to use this? I've tried GetSourceFilePath(typeof(MyClass).FullName), the result was MyNamespace.MyClass. So the input is the output.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I still have trouble using the method. When I do like you suggested, I receive an Error CS0117 'MyClass' does not contain a definition for 'GetSourceFilePath'

Comment: Well, is `GetSourceFilePath()` declared as `public static` in `MyClass`?

Comment: Well, no, of course not. When I have to copy the function in every class, then I wouldn't need much more time to get the structure manually. But as an attempt, I defined GetSourceFilePath as ExtensionMethod to object, so that every Type might be extended. Doesn't work either. In this case, I get the error MyClass is a Type which is not valid in the given context.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason for doing it from code? Because you can write a simple Batch script for example, to look for every .cs file in your folder:

dir *.cs /b /s

If you are planning on doing this in runtime using Reflection, I strongly recommend you NOT to do that, Reflection gives you a lot of flexibility yes, but it comes with a high performance cost, beware.

Regards!

Comment: I don't know, if reflection is needed. But I prefer doing this in code.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the full path to a code file, you can use a function in some helper class that uses the [`CallerFilePathAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute?view=netframework-4.8) like this :

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static string GetCallerFilePath([CallerFilePath] string callerPath = default)
    {
        return callerPath;
    }
}
```

and then call it without providing any parameter (since `callerPath` is optional and will be filled by the compiler) in the file you want the path of

```
string myPath = Helper.GetCallerFilePath();
```

Comment: Thank you very much nalka. Please see my comment to the answer, written by Mike Nakis

Comment: @EricNestrada yeah i just updated according to it, do you need any other info?

Answer (score 0):

This is technically not possible. Many have already pointed out, that you could declare a utility function that uses the `[CallerFilePath]` attribute, but you cannot get the path to the file a class is declared in from the class, because there is no relationship between a file and a class, other than the one we make. For all the compiler knows your class may as well be partial, and have implementations in different files. There is no one-to-one relationship between a class and a file.

So yes, the `[CallerFilePath]` works, but you may as well, just hardcode the path into the file, because there is no relation between class and file, as in the end your class gets compiled into an assembly and filepaths become irrelevant.

The thing to take away unfortunately is, is that what you are asking for is not inherentlypossible, and will not be at runtime, unless you do some manual work at compile time.

Fortunately however you do not have to write these helper functions you will undoubtedly need yourself, but could, for example, write a **source generator**, that injects a helper function returning the file path into every file containing a class, assuming you do not make use of partial classes. This is the best solution I can see here..

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
var dir = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        string path = dir+"\\MyClass.cs";
        string p= Path.GetFullPath(path);
```

Comment: Hey Syed, thanks for your answer, but that doesn't provide the needed information.